# Count and display values in a JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I have some data that looks like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
       "tags": [
           "design",
           "development",
           "code",
           "foo",
           "bar"
        ],
        "views": [
           "81"
        ]
        ...
    },
    {
       "tags": [
           "design",
           "foo",
           "photoshop",
           "alice",
           "bob"
         ],
        "views": [
           "28"
         ]
     ...
    }
```

What I'm hoping to do is loop through each data item, count up the tags, and then display how many times each one occurs. I don't want to go query each tag manually, though.

So ideally, I'd like it to display like this:

```
foo: 2
design: 2
alice: 1
```

and so on. Eventually, I'm hoping to incorporate it into a chart using Highcharts, Amcharts, or something similar?

The closest I've managed is this, taken from another solution on this site (and this doesn't create a full display, but I was first trying to get to grips with counting the values themselves, in any way possible):

```
$.getJSON('myarray.json', function(data) {

var occurrences = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
  if (data.data[i].tags == "foo") {
    occurrences++;
  }
}

console.log(occurrences);

});
```

But this output is incorrect. Any help at all would be appreciated. Once again, I would like to look through the tags for each dataset, and output a count for how many times each one occurs (ideally ranked in descending order).

Comment: how can you say this `data.data[i].tags == "foo"`, `data.data[i].tags` is an array and you are comparing with an string?

Comment: I was attempting to use this: http://jsperf.com/counting-occurrences-of-a-specific-value-in-an-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You correctly loop through each item, but you forget that "tags" in each item is a list of items as well.

```
$.getJSON('myarray.json', function(data) {

  var tagcount = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
    var item = data.data[i];
    if( item.tags != undefined ) {
      for (var j = 0; j < item.tags.length; j++) {
        var tag = item.tags[j];
        if( tagcount[tag] == undefined ) {
          tagcount[tag] = 1;
        } else {
          tagcount[tag]++;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  console.log(tagcount);

});
```

Comment: Thanks! I get an 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined' error with this too-- I'd been getting it before as well, and I'm not sure how I'm using .length incorrectly.

Comment: I have updated my code to include a check if 'tags' actually exists on the item we are checking. It seems that we have items without tags in the collection. I think it would have been more sensible to have `"tags":[]` instead of omitting it completely, but this will work too I guess.

Comment: Excellent, that was the problem, thank you very much! I had a few pieces of data that were empty/had no tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (data.data[i].tags.indexOf("foo") != -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result you want with iterating over your data, I've taken your data like so as an example:

```
var data = {
    "data": [{
        "tags": [
            "design",
            "development",
            "code",
            "foo",
            "bar"],
           "views": [
            "81"]
    }, {
        "tags": [
            "design",
            "foo",
            "photoshop",
            "alice",
            "bob"],
            "views": [
            "28"]

    }]
};
```

Then we can iterate over it like so:

```
var countArray = [];
$.each(data.data, function(dataKey, dataValue) {
    $.each(dataValue.tags, function(tagKey, tagValue) {
        if( !(tagValue in countArray) ) {
            countArray[tagValue] = 1;    
        } else {
            countArray[tagValue]++;
        }
    });
});
```

Console log would output

```
console.log(countArray);

[design: 2, development: 1, code: 1, foo: 2, bar: 1…]
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/602puhja/

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure why, but I get a TypeError with that: 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'?

Comment: Could be that your data array is slightly different in format than in my example

Comment: Well, you could show the whole data structure of which you are iterating over, I'm guessing it has something to do with the first iteration where I used the variable name "data", you might have used a different variable name to assign your data structure to.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = {};

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < data[i].tags.length; j++){

        var prop = data[i].tags[j];        
        result[prop] = !result[prop] ? 1 : result[prop] + 1;
    }
}

console.log(result);
// Object {design: 2, development: 1, code: 1, foo: 2, bar: 1…}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v0rhxvff/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a dictionary to count all the occurrences, then roll it in an array and sort it (if you want the same result as your output:

```
// this will count per string each occurrence
var occurrencies = {};

function fetchAndSort(data) {

  var i,j;

  for (i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
    var tags = data.data[i].tags;
    // now iterate inside tags
    for( j=0; j < tags.length; j++){
      // if there's not yet an entry in the dictionary, just create it
      if(!occurrencies[tags[j]]){
        occurrencies[tags[j]] = 0;
      }
      occurrencies[tags[j]]++;
    }
  }

  // at this point there's an object with all the keys and the relative count
  // if you want an ordered list you have to use an array because iterate on object
  // keys in JS [doesn't guarantee any order][1]
  var array = [];
  for( i in occurrencies ){
    array.push({name: i, count: occurrencies[i]});
  }

 // now sort it
 array.sort(function(entry1, entry2){
    // sort the array descending
    return entry2.count - entry1.count;
 });

 for( i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
   console.log(array[i].name + ':' + array.count);
 }

};

$.getJSON('myarray.json', fetchAndSort);
```

The solution is a bit long due to explanation purposes. You can take this and optimise to your needs in case by shortening some bits.